# Servlet.init() and Filter.init() call sequence

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

In which order are Servlet.init() and Filter.init() methods called in java web application? Which one is called first? Are all Servlet.init() methods called before than any Filter.doFilter method?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The filters are always initialized during webapp's startup in the order as they are defined in the `web.xml`.

The servlets are by default initialized during the first HTTP request on their url-pattern only. But you can configure them as well to initialize during webapp's startup using the `<load-on-startup>` entries wherein you can specify their priority. They will then be loaded in the priority order.
E.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If there are more servlets with the same priority order, then the loading order for those servlets is unspecified and may be arbitrary. Servlets are however in any way initialized *after* the initialization of filters, but *before* invocation of the filters.

Comment: If I have set load-on-startup in web.xml, can I be certain that this servlet's init() is called before any filter's doFilter?

Comment: Yes, I edited that in. This is however regardless of `load-on-startup`.

Comment: @kukudas: You're welcome. This related answer may be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909

Comment: @BalusC: The order of filter initiliazation doesn't depend on the order defined in the web.xml as Jan Gutvirth pointed out - tested on Apache Tomcat 6.0.37

Comment: Same comment as @Kroky -- see the important answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16237835/385667

Answer (score 7):

1. For all filters: **`Filter.init()`**
2. For all servlets with `<load-on-startup>` in `web.xml`: **`Servlet.init()`**
3. For all applicable filters for request: **`Filter.doFilter()`**
4. If applicable servlet not already initialised: **`Servlet.init()`**
5. For applicable servlet: **`Servlet.service()`**

Comment: This contradicts BalusC's answer, which would have your (4) happen before (3).

Comment: (2) is for servlets that have load-on-startup in the web.xml. (4) is for servlets that are initialized on first request to the servlet.

Answer (score 6):

Just a side note - I experienced on tomcat (7.0.30) that the Filter.init() methods are run in random order (iteration over HashMap).

Comment: This should be an comment.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation. But I thought it worth mentioning that the accepted answer seems to be wrong in this aspect (that is the order of calling Filter.init() method is generally undefined)

Answer (score -1):

Beware. I've been witnessing concurrent invocation of Filter.init() and Filter.doFilter() on the same instance. I'm still shocked and can't recover. Its' name is Jetty.